# Selecting specific elements and printing the number of them in a Queue

Tags: java, timestamp, queue

i created a queue (generic) that has a String and time-stamp value as each element. Now i'm trying to select elements that have their timestamps older than an hour and printing out their sums and other operations. I have looked at java.util.Queue's methods and none have that capability.

Please how do i go about it?

Comment: Do you have any code?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The `contains()` method is not working? Then your element needs `equalsTo()` and `hashCode()` coded properly.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I figured out how to do what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try a PriorityQueue

```
Queue<Type> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<Type>(20, new Comparator<Type>() {

  public int compare(Type o1, Type o2) {
    //Do compare based in criterio for sorting queue by timestamps
  }
});
```